# How to display threads for specific categories

Tags: php, html, mysql, while-loop

I'm making forum website and in my db i have tables categories and forum threads. Forum threads has a column category_id to know in which cat it is. Im trying to display it with this code:

```
while($category = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_categories)){
    echo 
    "<div class='category'>
        <h4 class='cat-name'>".$category['name']."</h4>
        <div class='cat-threads'>
        <ul>"; 
    while($thread = mysqli_fetch_array($result_threads) and $thread['category_id'] == $category['id']){
        echo "<a href='showthread/?id=".$thread['id']."'><li>".$thread['title']."</li></a>";
    }
    echo "</ul>
    </div>
    </div>";
} 
?>
```

But when i create two categories and two threads one for each of categories, it only displays threads for first category, and dosent for second one.

Comment: Hint: once you've looped through a result set, there are not more results, so you can't loop it again. If you need to use results twice, put them in an array first and then you can loop them as many times as you need

Comment: can you tell me what i have to do i dont understand u

Comment: Read my last sentence again, I explained exactly what to do